# How to set custom console by default in Eclipse plug-in project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, console

I have a custom Eclipse console. I need to set this console by default on project load (see attachment). Any solution will be helpful. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Well you need to customize your perspective such that the custom console is always part of the perspective....if you want to do it programmitcally you can use the perpsective apis.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [perspective extensions](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_perspectiveExtensions.html) or [create your own perspective](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_a_new_perspective%3F) to place the Console View at the desired location. However, the [Console View](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fconsole%2Fref-console_view.htm), does not show any specific console when it is shown.

To bring up your console page you'd need to listen for the Console View to become visible and then select the desired console.

An `IPartListener` that can be registered at the `IPartService` (or `IWorkbenchPage`) will tell you when a view is opened.

But great care must be taken to avoid unwanted side effects, e.g. a user may be in the process to open a specific console and certainly won't be amused if your listener code switches to a differnt console.